# Incorrect? "This was deemed the bodies corporate decision"

Tags: apostrophe, postpositive

I just got a letter from my body corporate, and it had in it, "this was deemed the bodies corporate decision."

This doesn't seem right to me, since "bodies corporate" is the plural - one body corporate, two bodies corporate.  The decision here "belongs" to only one body corporate, so shouldn't it have an apostrophe instead?  To me it seems it should read either "the body corporate's decision" or perhaps "the body's corporate decision".

After all, you refer to the "colour of the body's skin" not the "colour of the bodies skin".

Which is the correct usage for a decision that belongs to a body corporate?

Comment: OTOH "the body's corporate decision" is ambiguous. The phrasing might be better as "this was the decision of the body corporate."

Comment: *Bodies corporate* is obviously wrong. There ought to be an ELU question about how to form possessives with a post-positive adjective like *corporate* here, but I can't find one.

Comment: I suspect that the authors themselves got confused about how to form a genitive with a postpositive adjective, and that they ultimately decided to give up and hope nobody would notice.

Comment: They are just bad writers. :)

Comment: It was probably dictated, and that's the way it's pronounced. Somebody else typed it up later and they heard _bodies_ instead of _body's_, which is natural since they're identical. The fact is that neither makes sense; they both sound like nonsense, just not the nonsense that was intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body corporate is a noun phrase – a name/title.

**“The bodies corporate decision."* -> “bodies corporate” is the plural of “body corporate.” But the plural is rarely used as an attributive noun and the reading of this unlikely phrase would always be “The corporate decision of the bodies.

*"the body's corporate decision"*. = the corporate decision of the body. (Correct but not the intended meaning,)

"The body-corporate's decision" = the decision of the body corporate. This is correct: see the [United Nations website](https://www.un.org/sg/en/content/sg/statement/2019-05-30/the-secretary-generals-address-the-international-charlemagne-prize-of-aachen-for-the-unity-of-europe-delivered-multilingual-scroll-down-for-all-english-version)

> The Secretary-General's address at the International Charlemagne Prize of Aachen for the Unity of Europe

You will note that a hyphen has been added for essential clarity. This is useful for separating

"[the body's] [corporate decision]" from "[the body-corporate’s] decision"

Comment: As the **body corporate** entry in [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/body-corporate) explicitly says: *plural **bodies corporate***. I'd have thought that was General Reference for this site.

Comment: -1. *Secretary-General* is usually hyphenated; *body corporate* is not.

Comment: @AndrewLeach You may note: *You will note that a hyphen has been added for essential clarity.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers - and the genitive?

Comment: @Greybeard If you meant that sentence to refer to "body-corporate" instead of "Secretary-General", it's rather in the wrong place. But "This is correct" is in the wrong place too, because "body-corporate" is **not** correct.

Comment: @AndrewLeach *"body-corporate" is not correct."* I don't think I could be that prescriptive when what is needed is clarity. We speak to express meaning: punctuation is there to aid. Hence your use of inverted commas.